# How to map through a deeply nested array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

```
const my_arr = [
   {id: 1, arr: [{subId: 1, value: 1}],
   {id: 2, arr: [{subId: 2, value: 2}],
   {id: 3, arr: [{subId: 3, value: 1}],
]
```

how do I map over this array `my_arr` and then map over `arr` to return an array like so:

```
[
  {subId: 1, value: 1},
  {subId: 3, value: 1},
]
```

basically filtering out only where values are 1 and then returning only that sub object

I've tried doing

```
my_arr.map((x) => x.map((y) => y.value === 1 ? y : null))
```

Comment: [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatmap) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) might help

Comment: Hi Red Baron, can you clarify what you've tried & highlight which parts you're getting stuck with? For a starting point, you can look at a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) with an [`if` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else), or you can look into methods such as [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) & [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: @NickParsons edited to show

Comment: `map` collects all results; it seems like you’re actually trying to `filter` (or `reduce`).

Comment: Your data isn't valid. You're missing `}` from each of those objects.

Comment: @Andy that was rushed pseudo code, assume it's correct

Comment: Please try: `console.log(my_arr.flatMap(({arr}) => arr).filter(({value}) => value === 1));` and share your feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this approach with [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const my_arr = [
   {id: 1, arr: [{subId: 1, value: 1}]},
   {id: 2, arr: [{subId: 2, value: 2}]},
   {id: 3, arr: [{subId: 3, value: 1}]},
]

const result = my_arr.flatMap(item => item.arr).filter(item => item.value === 1)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach maps over the outer array `my_arr`, and then uses an inner map to map over the inner array. Since [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) always returns an array, you'll end up mapping your objects from your outer array to other arrays, which you don't want. You can instead use [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) which will combine/join the returned inner arrays into one array. However, rather than using `.map()` as your inner method though, you should use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to create an array of objects that have a `value` of `1`, which then gets merged into your resulting outer array created by the `.flatMap()` method:

```js
const my_arr = [ {id: 1, arr: [{subId: 1, value: 1}]}, {id: 2, arr: [{subId: 2, value: 2}]}, {id: 3, arr: [{subId: 3, value: 1}]}, ];

const res = my_arr.flatMap(({arr}) => arr.filter(({value}) => value === 1));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with nested structure, you will have to get little creative.

- First you will have to filter the array.
- Inside it, you can use `.some` to check if your condition matches and return matching
- Now you have the filtered list but you still need to format your output. You can use `.reduce` and concat `arr` of every item

This will be useful if you have multiple items in `arr`.

```js
const my_arr = [
   {id: 1, arr: [{subId: 1, value: 1}] },
   {id: 2, arr: [{subId: 2, value: 2}] },
   {id: 3, arr: [{subId: 3, value: 1}] },
]

const output = my_arr
  .filter(({ arr }) =>
    arr.some(({value}) => value === 1)
  ).reduce((acc, { arr }) => acc.concat(arr), [])
  
console.log(output)
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing something similar at first, but if one of the objects (such as the first one) has an `arr` of `arr: [{subId: 1, value: 1}, {subId: 1.5, value: 2}]`, then `{subId: 1.5, value: 2}` will be included in the result, whereas I believe OP only wants objects with a value of `1`

Comment: Fair point but that is inconclusive based on the data OP has shared. So I'll keep the answer just in case someone has this usecase